# Master detail view with subdetail view and bindings

Tags: objective-c, binding, nsarraycontroller, master-detail

I try to make a Master Detail View with an additional Detaildetail View with bindings in the interface builder. The whole application is for Mac OSX.

I have 3 table views. Master-Table, DetailsOfMaster-Table and DetailsOfDetails-Table
For each tableview i have an array controller.

My Data structure is an array filled with Objects like the following one:

```
@interface Node : NSObject
   @property (strong)NSString* name;
   @property (assign)NSArray* details;
@end
```

Each node's detail is filled again with other nodes.

- The Master-ArrayController's content-array is bound to my array of
  nodes.
- The Details-ArrayController's content-array is bound to
  Master-ArrayController's Selection.details
- The DetailDetails-ArrayController's content-array is bound to the
  Details-ArrayController's Selection.details

Each tabel view's Content is bound to the corresponding array controller with the Key, arrangedObjects and the Tabel Column to arrangedObjects.name

Everything compiles fine.
The Problem is the Detail- and DetailsDetail-Table are not getting updated.
[image: Detail views are not getting updated]

Did I missed some bindings? 
I would like to be able to show my data-structure completely with bindings who were set with the interface builder.

Comment: Try removing the table view binding -- I never use that when binding to an array controller.  Just bind the column to array controller arrangedObjects.name and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but if i remove them the application crashes if i click an item from the first table. I think the bindings to the tableview are necessary to let the tableview know how many items have to be shown and stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need that binding on one column tables.  I noticed that your details property is declared as "assign".  Try changing that to retain and see if that helps.

Comment: Waah, that was it!! Thanks a lot! I was so focused on the bindings that i didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings are all correct, there mistake was the wrong attribute of the property 
    @property (assign)NSArray* details;
needs to be
    @property (retrain)NSArray* details;